# I want to insert values in a @temp or #table returned by CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE #DaysTable(tdays datetime)
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from

    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH

CTE_Days AS

(

SELECT DATEADD(month, @month, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(@dataforDate), DATEADD(day, -DAY(@dataforDate) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@dataforDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)))) Days

UNION ALL

SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Days)

FROM CTE_Days

WHERE Days < DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(month, @month, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(@dataforDate), DATEADD(day, -DAY(@dataforDate) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@dataforDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))))))

)

insert into #dayatable
select * from
    (
SELECT DATEADD(month, @month, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(@dataforDate), DATEADD(day, -DAY(@dataforDate) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@dataforDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)))) Days

UNION ALL

SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Days)

FROM CTE_Days

WHERE Days < DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(month, @month, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(@dataforDate), DATEADD(day, -DAY(@dataforDate) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@dataforDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))))))
)
```

But this gives me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong you have repeated same condition after insert into statement which is already there in CTE and if that's the case then you can simply write as below:

```
WITH CTE_Days AS
(
SELECT DATEADD(month, @month, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(@dataforDate), DATEADD(day, -DAY(@dataforDate) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@dataforDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)))) Days
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Days)
FROM CTE_Days
WHERE Days < DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(month, @month, DATEADD(month, -MONTH(@dataforDate), DATEADD(day, -DAY(@dataforDate) + 1, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@dataforDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))))))
)
insert into #DaysTable
select * from CTE_Days;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Each select, insert, update or delete is a separate statement.
- So each one needs the CTE
  expression.
- Only the first one has it.